# count integer once it's converted from string to integer?? swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to increase the integer by 1, like this

```
var myInt = 1
var myString = Int(myInt)

func increaseInt() {
    myInt = myInt + 1
}
```

But I can't seem to access the integer once it's converted to a string

Comment: You're not converting the integer to a String.  If you want to do that you could say `var myString = "\(myInt)"`.  Either way, your code above should work.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Did you call `increaseInt`? did you got an error? please try to make it more clear

Comment: Line #1: I think it's much better to explicitly type it as an Int. Line #2: The result isn't a String, it's an Int (and based one the previous line, very redundant). Function processing, not very Swiftly coded.

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myInt` is a value type and not a reference. So once you convert `myInt` to a string (which should be done like this: `var myString = "\(myInt)"`) any changes made to `myInt` have no effect on `myString`.

If you want to make sure that `myString` always equals the string representation of `myInt`, you can make `myString` a computed property...

```
var myString: String {
  get {
    return "\(myInt)"
  }
}
```

Comment: `var myString: String { return String(myInt) }`